# WCF call is not occuring in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8.1

I have created WCF service which is returning large number of data in memory size. Its headache for me, sometimes it gives results and after couple of hours, when I try to invoke,it gives error.

```
"System.ServiceModel.Commmunication Exception"
```

Here is my web.config file:

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
 <binding name="webBinding" sendTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
   maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
 </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Please suggest me and help me out. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be facing memory issues. This: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn645469.aspx and you should be able to confirm or deny this.

Comment: Jeff sanders, thanks you so much man, is there a way to reduce memory usage? How to overcome this issue?